# Display Userform that exists in Add-in

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have saved my project, which contains a form, as .xla.

I would like to use this add in in another excel projects. If I add this add in in another projects. Is there a way to run directly my forms (and not forstly going to Visual basic and then run the form)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly...
u need to have sub that call's the form

```
sub showMyForm()
   myForm.show
end sub
```

add this code in add-in and call it from inside workbook that references the add-in (eg. via button).